# CakePHP 4 MIddleware return withStatus and break execution script

Tags: cakephp-4.x

routes.php

```
$routes->applyMiddleware('MyMiddleware');
```

Application.php

```
public function routes(\Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder $routes): void {
    $options = [
        'httponly' => true,
    ];
    $routes->registerMiddleware('csrf', new CsrfProtectionMiddleware($options));
    
    $routes->registerMiddleware('MyMiddleware', new Middleware\MyMiddleware());
    parent::routes($routes);
}
```

src/Middleware/MyMiddleware.php

```
public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface {

        $response = $handler->handle($request);
  
        return $response->withStatus(401,'Fail');
}
```

It correctly response the httpd 401 code, but the script continues to work, passing through the controller and view.

I would like to stop the execution by returning an http code other than 200. In cakephp 4 not work.

Can someone tell me how I can return http 401 and break the script.

Comment: The `->handle()` call is what results in the controller being called. If you don't want that to happen, then you need to avoid that call ever happening.

Comment: When I return another type of data it displays the following error....Return value of App\\Middleware\\MyMiddleware::process() must be an instance of Psr\\Http\\Message\\ResponseInterface, int returned

Comment: That's not at all what I'm saying. Your code is calling `handle` and then returning a response. The `handle` call is what calls the controller. You say "the script continues to work, passing through the controller and view", but that's not what's going on. The script has actually *already passed through the controller and view* before it gets to the return. What is your goal with this middleware? To always return a 401 status and never ever run the controller? If so, then just remove the `handle` call entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The only form which I found its not use the method process, even in the cakePHP 4 I used the method __invoke and i can get the result expected